# Same push declined by Git Bash in GitHub but okay in git csm

Tags: github, permission-denied

I made the same push request to my remote repository on github as in git csm. Git csm succeed but github  rejet with permission denied error.

[image: 403 error from github]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases (git scm or GitHub client), you need to check what `git remote -v` returns, and see if you are in the same folder.

You can also change the remote url in order to make sure the right user is expected:

```
git remote set-url origin https://AudiencePropensities@github.com/AudiencePropensities/image_template
```

That way, it will ask for the `AudiencePropensities`'s account password.

Comment: Hi VonC, I understand that AudiencePropensities isn't a repo but image_template is. you can see that fatal reads " unable to access audiencepropensities/image_template.git. I will check git remote -v and thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @user3339918 Right, I have remove the first part of the answer, and I have added another suggestion.